# Do I need to rebase to master before pushing any of my feature branch commit to remote

Tags: git

I have recently started looking into git rebase.

Based on some personal exercises, what I have noticed is if I rebase my feature branch to master after pushing the local commits on my feature to remote, I will run into a scenario of the local feature branch being behind remote by x no. of commits when attempting to push to origin.

I had to force push in this scenario, and I did read about the risks of force push.
However, I wanted to understand was when is the best time in our workflow to rebase (not rebase vs merge)

Here is a scenario to better illustrate it:

commit a: common ancestor

feature: commit b, commit d, commit e
master: commit c, commit f, commit g

master is pushed to remote.
feature is pushed to remote.

git commands:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

This cause conflict and I need to resolve the conflict first, and then do a force git push otherwise I run into infinite loop.

So, what I'm trying to understand is should I rebase first and then only push those commit c,f and g to remote?

May be this is a standard known practice already. I tried searching but did not find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rebasing first and pushing new commits is a very common workflow.

Different repositories/organisations have different standards for what they expect, but what you're doing is a perfectly reasonable way to contribute changes.